# Best way to store measurement units for Django model's fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a product model which has a lot of fields with all the product's specs such as *width*, *weight*, and a lot of other. I want to display a table with all specs, so I decided to iterate through my model's fields and display the table with a field name + value + measurement units in my template. I'm storing field name in a verbose_name attribute and field description in the help_text attribute, but I'm curious what is the best way to store a particular measurement unit for a specific field?

Comment: isn't the measurement unit fixed for each field? Then it's just a matter of displaying, so you can just add a `@property` to your model that displays the field with its measurement unit.

Comment: @dirkgroten In this case, I still need to create a property function for each field, so there will be a lot of property functions in my model since it has a lot of fields. Anyway, thank you! Seems like this is the best solution that I can use.